# How to draw a line or select something in using qvtkwidget?

Tags: qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I successfully made a program by using `qvtkwidget`, showing a few lines and points. And everything works perfectly. Next, I want to add an `edit` mode to my program, so that I can draw a line on it, or select some points or lines from it. Could anyone give me some guidelines for doing that? Do I need to use `vtkRenderWindowInteractor`? I tried to google but still can't find any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to work with vtkinteraction, vtkobserver- callback, and vtkselection modules. and this example also useful http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/MoveAVertex HTH

And here is set of examples you may find relavent to your goal
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#User_Interaction